# Zend 2 redirect() module error

Tags: zend-framework2

I have made a checklogin fucntion to check `$auth->getIdentity(),` but i am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Admin\Module::redirect() in
>   C:\xampp\websites\zend2\module\Admin\Module.php on line 51

How can i fix this?

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setLayoutTitle'));

    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);

    // add event
    $eventManager->attach('render', array($this, 'checklogin')); 


}


public function checkLogin()
{   
    $auth = new AuthenticationService();
    if( $auth->getIdentity() == NULL ){
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('/admin/login');  
    }else{
       return $this->redirect()->toRoute('/admin'); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because there is no `redirect` method in `Module` class.

I suggest move this check in `dispatch` event, because `dispatch` event is triggered **before** the controller action is dispatched.

So you need to change the listener method setting in onBootstrap Module method:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    // ...
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'checkLogin'));
    // ...
}
```

Then in the listener method you got the `MvcEvent` where `target` is matched controller class:

```
public function checkLogin(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $controller = $e->getTarget();
    if ($someCondition) {
        return $controller->plugin('redirect')->toRoute('your/route/name');
    }
}
```

Comment: This was what i was looking for, thnx!

Answer (score 0):

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener();
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager);
    $app = $e->getParam('application');
    $app->getEventManager()->attach('render', array($this, 'setLayoutTitle'));
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'checkLogin'));
}

public function checkLogin(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $iden = new AuthenticationService();
    if( $iden->getIdentity() === NULL ){
        $matches    = $e->getRouteMatch();
        $controller = $matches->getParam('controller');
        $getController = explode( '\\', $controller );      
    if( $getController[2] != 'Login' ){
        $controller = $e->getTarget();
        return $controller->plugin('redirect')->toRoute('login');
    }
}
```